# How to stop mediaplayer being played in a class when app is minimized/closed?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a fragment that calls a class which has a mediaplayer in it. On minimizing or closing the app, the mediaplayer continues to play. If the mediaplayer is part of the activity then I can use onPause and onStop methods in which I can say mediaplayer.release() to stop it. Is there something similar that I can do in a class to stop the mediaplayer?

Comment: Assuming that the media player is a static member of the class you refer to, you simply need to override `onPause` for the activity that is in the foreground and tell the class to pause it's media player?

Comment: @Luke Park, your suggestion worked perfectly. I declared the mediaplayer as static in the class. Then I added the code xyzclass.mediaplayer.stop(); and  xyzclass.mediaplayer.release(); in the onPause and onStop methods of the activity. That solved the issue. Thanks a lot. You should write your suggestion as the answer.

Comment: You're welcome, remember to mark it correct if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare the media player as `static` in the class, you can start and stop it in your activities `onPause` and `onResume` methods by referencing it through the class name.